# Expected number of matches

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

"Two shuffled decks are laid out one beneath another...what is the expected number of matches" (match is same rank and suit)

Part where i am stuck-

Does the probability at each draw for a match stays same equal to $\frac{1}{52}$. Shouldnt the probability of a match on the second draw be $\frac{1}{51}$ if there was a match on the first draw

and $\frac{1}{50}$ if there wasn't a match on the first draw

How does one go from here to computing the expected value?

Edit:  Looking to understand why Expected value at ith draw is always same at $\frac{1}{52}$...to me it looks like the probability at ith draw would depend on previous draws.

Comment: Hint: Expectation is linear. What is the expected number of matches in the $i$th position?

Comment: I dont understand how Probability for a match at ith draw would be constant at 1/52..

Comment: Whatever the $i$th card in the first deck is, there is a $1/52$ chance that the $i$th card in the second deck is the same card.